# NavHostFragment vs FragmentContainerView [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

Hi there I'm going through the guides for navigation on the developer Android site, and I followed the instructions to create a `NavHostFragment`:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

However when that code is there the IDE suggests that I replace the `NavHostFragment` with `FragmentContainerView`.

What is the difference and when should they each be used rather than the other?

Thank you

Comment: i'm not as it always showed me that hint to to change to fragmentcontainerview but it always crashed for me ,  fragmentcontainerview is like a framelayout i guess , i always continue with fragment

Comment: @takieddine if the crash happens in the `findNavController` check the answer below.

Comment: As i read in the documentation , the FragmentContainview extends framelayout and it is useful when it comes to implementing transactions where as NavHostFramgent is necessary for navigation to work as it acts as controller all of the fragments and make them transactions , if something is wrong , please correct me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FragmentContainerView` is a customized Layout designed specifically  as the container for Fragments. The `NavHostFragment` is responsible for swapping destinations in the Navigation component.

You can use:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/xxxxx"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"

    ..>
```

and:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Or you can use:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/xxxx"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"

    ..>
```

with:

```
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: ah so i guess the answer is to typecast that FragmentConainerView to NavhostFragment ?

Comment: @takieddine It is required if you are using the code in the OnCreate method (most of cases). The reason is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment2)

Answer (score 2):

If you explore the source code of **FragmentContainerView**, you will find it *extends* FrameLayout.

**FragmentContainerView** includes all features found in **Framelayout**, with some added features in Fragment Transition and etc..

Note: FragmentContainerView replaces `<FrameLayout>` and `<fragment>` not NavHostFragment.

To know more about FragmentContainerView, kindly check [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragmentcontainerview-292f393f9ccf).

I hope this would help.